# changing mysql password via java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to change a user's password on mysql using java,
i successfully changed it on phpmyadmin
but same command doesnt work on java

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('12345')
```

this command will change the current logged in user, i have tried it on java like this

```
statement = connect.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('12345')");
```

but nothing happened

i also tried this with root logged in

```
statement = connect.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456')");
```

and nothing work,, any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `executeQuery()` method not `executeUpdate()`

```
statement = connect.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery("SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456')");
```

**Note** only known password can be changed using the above query.

for example if root password is `example` then for creating connection we use

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "example");
```

So using this connection we can only change present password.

The following is an example based on [this code at roseindia.net](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/core/changeRootPassword.html):

```
import java.sql.*;
class ChangeRootPassword
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
                try{
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "example");
                        String sql = "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('test')";
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                        stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                        stmt.close();
                        conn.close();
                        System.out.println("Password is changed successfully!");
                        }
                catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }
}
```

So the new mysql root password now is **test**

Comment: You need to use [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) only for any Insert, Update or Delete query.

Comment: @R.J yes true but for this case executeQuery should be used

Comment: I really doubt if the problem is with the choice of `executeUpdate()` or `executeQuery()`. It seems to be more of a problem with the query, as such.

Comment: @R.J  query is right and OP is using executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery().If you are downvoter then remove it.

Comment: @OsamaAbukmail are you giving the correct username?See In my computer I am changing the root password like this way **String sql = "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456')";
Statement smt = con.createStatement();
smt.executeQuery(sql)**

Comment: If you can explain why `executeQuery()` is to be used instead of `executeUpdate()`, I would revoke the *-1*. But then, voting is upto me. You can't influence my vote just because you don't like it.

Comment: @javaBeginner yes i saw the answer , but same problem, have you tried to connect again with the new password ?

Comment: @OsamaAbukmail just copy the code of my answer.replace example(my root password) to your original password and run

Comment: @javaBeginner everything is working now :) thnx man u saved me :)

Comment: (Just for your information: the voting on this answer is the base [for a discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203937/rules-of-downvoting-an-answer).)

Comment: Credit is required; plagiarism not allowed! Why did you rollback my edit?

Comment: Again, why did you remove the attribution?

Comment: Do not roll back the attribution of the source of your code. This is your last warning.

Comment: @BradLarson sorry I **will not** rollback any more